# Asymptotics of a sum involving factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I'm interested in the large-$n$ behavior of the sum
$$a(m,n) = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{x^k}{k! (n-k)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

For the new question, here is the answer.

Suppose $x>0$. Let's define $p= \frac{x}{x+1}$, then $x = \frac{p}{1-p}$. We have

$$\begin{align}
a(m,n) &=\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{x^k}{k! (n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{p^m}{(1-p)^m}\cdot \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{n!(1-p)^n}\color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^m  \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot p^m(1-p)^{n-m}}\\
\end{align}$$

Let's define $Y_n$ following the [binominal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) $B(n,p)$, then the term in red color is exacly the [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) $P(Y_n\le m)$.

We know that the binominal distribution $B(n,p)$ is a [sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Expected_value_and_variance) of $n$ i.i.d Bernoulli random variable, then

$$P(Y_n\le m) = P(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k \le m) = P(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k \le \frac{m}{n})$$

According to the central limit theorem, for $n$ large, the random variable $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ follow the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(p,p(1-p))$, then
$$\begin{align}
P(Y_n\le m) \sim P(\mathcal{N}(p,p(1-p))\le \frac{m}{n})&= P\left(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}  \left(\frac{m}{n} -p \right)\right)\\
&=\Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}  \left(\frac{m}{n} -p \right)\right)
\end{align}$$
with $\Phi(.)$ the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

Finally, for $n$ large, using the [Stirling's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we have the following approximation

$$\begin{align}
a(m,n) &\sim \frac{1}{n!(1-p)^n}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}  \left(\frac{m}{n} -p \right)\right)\\
&\sim  \color{blue}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(\frac{e(x+1)}{n}\right)^n\Phi\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}}  \left(\frac{m}{n} -\frac{x}{x+1} \right)\right)}
\end{align}$$

Q.E.D

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n= \frac{(x+1)^n}{n!}$$
Use the [Stirling formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), for $n\to+\infty$
$$a_n \sim  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \left(\frac{e(x+1)}{n} \right)^n $$

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question.